# How can we get the best value of a contour area?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to calculate precise values of an area of a contour of a potato moving in a conveyer belt. How can I take the average value of all areas printed in OpenCV, so that I can get the single value which could be taken reference for the project?

**my code**

```
for cnt in contours:
    area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > 100:
        areaAr = np.array([area])
        meanArea = statistics.mean(areaAr)
        print(meanArea)
```

Comment: Create a list, append the area of each contour to the list and calculate the average of the list

Comment: Another variation of the same idea. If you don’t need to keep track of all the areas  and just need an average, just sum-accumulate the area and divide by the number of processed samples, that way you avoid storing each individual value in an array.